# Rails sort by column on multiple tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm attempting to do a SQL sort in rails by sorting on a column in multiple tables.

Both Event and Featured models have a column called "date". An event can belong_to a Featured. I'd like to be able to join these two columns together and sort by this date column on both. So if the date of a Featured is 24/05/12 and the date of an Event is 23/05/12, then the Event date would display first.

I'd prefer to do this in SQL (not using a Ruby sort).

Thanks!

Edit:

```
.order("events.date ASC, featureds.date ASC")
```

Will not work because this will pull back first the events in order, then the featureds in order.

**For example:**

Event 1 date: 23/04/12

Event 2 date: 24/04/12

Featured 1 date: 23/04/12

**What I want the sql to pull back is:**

Event 1 date: 23/04/12

Featured 1 date: 23/04/12

Event 2 date: 24/04/12

**Ordering like above will pull it through like so:**

Event 1 date: 23/04/12

Event 2 date: 24/04/12

Featured 1 date: 23/04/12

Comment: Can you post your existing SQL please

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are using ActiveRecord? Add this to your ActiveRecord query:

```
.order("events.date ASC, featureds.date ASC")
```

Table names are my guess.. (`featureds`?)

Also see [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering).

Comment: That will show the events first and then the featureds which is not what I am trying to achieve. I've updated the original post to reflect what I mean.

Comment: I think you cannot retrieve a mix of records like that. The easiest way is to do two queries and join the sets after retrieval.

Comment: I ended up creating a separate table that holds the event dates which alleviated the issue.